# My uncle has a flight tomorrow morning for Malaysia but we found a mistake in his e-visa - his name has a typo. What should we do?

Tags: malaysia

My uncle's name is Dayaram but in his e-visa his name has been spelled Dayram. In all supporting documents he's correctly listed as Dayaram.

His flight leaves tomorrow morning.

What should we do?

Comment: Can you submit another request?

Answer (score 6):

As long as everything else on the visa matches (passport number, birth date, etc), your uncle is *probably* OK.  Given that you don't really have time for other options, I would suggest just going to the airport and trying your luck, airlines are usually tolerant of small typos and inconsistencies in names.  Good luck and let us know how it went!

Comment: He tried his luck and successful reached Malaysia thankyou for your comments and suggestions

Comment: @BhabinBasnet Great! Please accept this answer (click the check mark) if it worked for you.

Comment: I would assume the visa is glued into the passport so this gives another proof that this visa is meant for this particular person, even if the name spelling doesn't match. If there are two physically separate documents where one has a spelling error in the name this becomes a lot more tricky and is much less likely to work out.

Comment: @quarague OP mentioned it's an **e**-visa, so no, there is no physical label in this case.